# Inequalities of Two i.i.d. Random Variables

Tags: statistics, inequality, random-variables

### The Problem

Let $X_1$ and $X_2$ be a continuous i.i.d. random variables.  By definition, we know that...

1. Independence: $\mathbb P(X_1 \in A \ \cap \ X_2 \in B)=\mathbb P(X_1 \in A) \ \mathbb P(X_2 \in B)$
2. Identically Distributed: $\mathbb P(X_1 \le x) = \mathbb P(X_2 \le x) \ \ \forall \ \ x \in \mathbb R^1$

My hypothesis is that:
$$\mathbb P(X_1 > X_2) = 0.5$$
I have attempted to prove this by using the above definitions to form the expression:
$$\mathbb P(X_1 \ge x \ \cap \ X_2 < x)=\mathbb P(X_2 \ge x \ \cap \ X_1 < x) \ \ \forall \ \ x \in \mathbb R^1$$

### My Questions

1. Is this a valid proof, and am I missing anything?
2. This seems like a fundamental property of i.i.d. random variables.  Is this already a named theorem?

Comment: Your definition of identically distributed is wrong. For any two continuous random variables, $P(X_1=x)=P(X_2=x)=0$ for every $x$, but of course that doesn't mean that any two continuous r.v.'s are identically distributed. The correct definition is that two r.v.'s are identically distributed if $P(X_1 \le x)=P(X_2 \le x)$ for every $x$.

Comment: @CélioAugusto Oh, good catch!  You're absolutely right.  I made the correction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Hint

(From Andrew Yung)

> There is a standard trick involved here. Instead of giving you the full solution, let me point you in the right direction instead. Note that the probability you are interested in is equivalent to $\mathbb{P}(X_1 - X_2 > 0).$ Hence it would be enough to determine the cumulative distribution function of the variable $X_1 - X_2.$ For this it would be enough to first determine the CDF of $-X_2$ and then determine the CDF of the difference by explicitly computing the density of $X_1 - X_2$ in terms of the densities of $X_1$ and $-X_2$ (which you would have determined in the previous step). Is there any important Theorem that comes to mind when looking at it this way?
> Please do let me know if you manage to fill in the blanks by yourself and if not, I shall do that.

### Solution

Thank you for the hint, Andrew.  With your help I was able to find a solution.  Please let me know if you were thinking of an easier path to the answer.

- Because $X_1$ and $X_2$ are Identically Distributed, the CDF and PDF of each random variable can be represented as:
  $$F_X(x)=\mathbb P(X_1 \le x)=\mathbb P(X_2 \le x)$$
  $$f_X(x)=\frac d {dx} F_X(x)$$
- Note that:
  $$F_{-X_2}(x)=\mathbb P(-X_2 \le x)=\mathbb P(X_2 > -x)=1-F_X(-x)$$
- Also, the CDF of the sum of two Independent Continuous Random Variables ($X$ and $Y$) is:
  $$F_{X+Y}(a) = \mathbb P(X+Y \le a) = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f_X(x)F_Y(a-x)dx$$
- Therefore:
  $$\mathbb P(X_1 \le X_2)=\mathbb P(X_1 -X_2 \le 0)=$$
  $$F_{X_1-X_2}(0) = F_{X_1+(-X_2)}(0) =$$
  $$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f_X(x)\Bigl(1-F_X\bigl(0-(-x)\bigr)\Bigr)dx =$$
  $$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f_X(x)dx+\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f_X(x) \Bigl(-F_X(x)\Bigr)dx=$$
  $$1-\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f_X(x) \ F_X(x)dx = \ ...$$
- Then you can use Integration by Substution where $u=F_X(x)$:
  $$1-\int_{x=-\infty}^{x=+\infty} \biggl(\frac {du} {dx}\biggr)(u) dx=1-\int_{u=0}^{u=1} (u) du=1-\biggl[ \frac {u^2} {2} \biggr]_{0}^{1}=$$
  $$1-(0.5-0)=0.5$$

Comment: Your answer is correct. It is indeed true that this answer is a little bit long, but it touches a few key aspects that might come in handy to you later on. To get a shorter answer, note that the densities $f_{X_1 - X_2}$ and $f_{X_2 - X_1}$ coincide, so, in particular, $\mathbb{P}(X_1 - X_2 \leq 0) = \mathbb{P}(X_1 - X_2 \geq 0).$ But since $\mathbb{P}(X_1 = X_2) = 0$ for two such continuous random variables, we get that $1 = \mathbb{P}(X_1 - X_2 \geq 0) + \mathbb{P}(X_1 - X_2 \leq 0) = 2 \mathbb{P}(X_1 \leq X_2),$ so that indeed $\mathbb{P}(X_1 \leq X_2) \leq \frac{1}{2}.$

Comment: I like that answer a lot!  It's much more concise than what I did.  I just often miss these clever manipulations of equations and end up charging straight ahead.  Anyways, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

There is a standard trick involved here. Instead of giving you the full solution, let me point you in the right direction instead. Note that the probability you are interested in is equivalent to $\mathbb{P}(X_1 - X_2 > 0).$ Hence it would be enough to determine the cumulative distribution function of the variable $X_1 - X_2.$ For this it would be enough to first determine the CDF of $-X_2$ and then determine the CDF of the difference by explicitly computing the density of $X_1 - X_2$ in terms of the densities of $X_1$ and $-X_2$ (which you would have determined in the previous step). Is there any important Theorem that comes to mind when looking at it this way?

Please do let me know if you manage to fill in the blanks by yourself and if not, I shall do that.

Comment: Hi Andrew!  Thanks for the hint, it lead me to a solution.  I tried to add the solution to your Answer, but the Edit didn't go through.  So I just credited you in the answer I posted.  I hope this is okay with you.